# How to capture float and decimal numbers after equal sign REGEX

Tags: regex

I'm try to get float or decimal numbers with grep -P

Example= `jrockit.gc.latest.yc.number = 5034`;

I want to get just `5034`.

Here is my REGEX => `(?:\s*=\s*)([0-9.]+)` but it also get equal sign.

How to get only number?

Comment: Sorry , i forgot to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) which keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

```
grep -oP '\s*=\s*\K[0-9.]+' file
```

or

```
grep -oP '\s*=\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?' file
```